# Germany to Bulgaria travel EU permanent resident COVID

Tags: germany, covid-19, bulgaria

I have been trying to find information if travel from Germany to Bulgaria is permitted given I have EU permanent residency.

Germany was classified as a Red Zone Country two weeks ago: https://www.mfa.bg/en/customnews/main/24737

While it states EU citizens are allowed with full vaccinations and PCR test, there is no info about permanent residents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the wording of the [Ordinance](https://www.mfa.bg/en/customnews/main/24737), where for the **Green and Orange zones** the exceptions are for **all persons** from the listed countries, for the **Red zone** the exceptions are mainly for those who may exercise the **Freedom of Movement** (plus UK and countries listed in [Annex 4 of the Ordinance](https://www.mfa.bg/upload/73672/Annex%204.docx)) within the European Union.

Other 3rd country nationals, who are residents of the red zone countries, are therefore **excluded** from these exceptions.

The site of the [German Embassy, Sofia](https://sofia.diplo.de/bg-de/aktuelles/-/2318146) uses a similar wording, so you may assume that this is not a mistake.

---

**Sources**:

- [COVID-19 TRAVEL RESTRICTIONS - BULGARIA - valid as of 1st December 2021](https://www.mfa.bg/en/customnews/main/24737)

  - [Annex 4 of the Ordinance](https://www.mfa.bg/upload/73672/Annex%204.docx) (doxc)